# Sequelize: How to query model by 1:n association, but include all associated objects in a single query (PostgreSQL)

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a Ticket model with hasMany relation to Approval model (multi-level approval workflow). Approval belongsTo a User.

For a particular use case, I'll have to filter all the pending approvals to be made by a User and show him his to be approved Tickets.

Have solved like so -

```
models.Ticket.findAll({
  include: [{
            model: models.Approval,
            where: { userId: options.userId }
        }]
}).then(function(tickets){...
```

Gives me the filtered tickets but I've to also get the list of all approvals for the ticket to show the approval workflow. Can this be done by a single query in Sequelize?

```
Data (T is Ticket, A is Approval and U is User) -

T1 - A1/U1, A2/U2, A3/U3
T2 - A4/U2
T3 - A5/U1, A6/U4

Output for U1 -

T1 - A1/U1
T3 - A5/U1

Expected for U1 -

T1 - A1/U1, A2/U2, A3/U3
T3 - A5/U1, A6/U4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Found a workaround to solve it in one query.*

Update Ticket to have two associations on Approval with the same foreign key (one with an alias defined) -

```
Ticket.hasMany(models.Approval, {
  foreignKey: 'ticketId',
};
Ticket.hasMany(models.Approval, {
  as: 'ApprovalFilter',
  foreignKey: 'ticketId',
};
```

Then filter using multiple includes -

```
models.Ticket.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: models.Approval,
    as: 'ApprovalFilter',
    where: { userId: options.userId },
  }, {
    model: models.Approval,
  }]
}).then(function(tickets){...
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is kind of tricky** , but this way you can achieve the result in single query ,

```
models.Approval.findAll({
    where: { userId: options.userId } // <---- Get all the approvals for user
    include: [{
            model: models.Ticket, // <----- Get all tickets for it
            include: [{
                model: models.Approval // <---- Get all the approvals for that ticket
            }]
    }]
})
```

> **NOTE : I haven't tried this one but as long as I know this should
>   work.**

Comment: Thanks for the reply and it works definitely. But isn't it possible in any other way to do the query on Ticket as base model?User ID here is being used as an optional filter in a bigger use case.

Comment: @Himavanth , in that case you need to fetch the ticket's id first , means 2 queries , that way you can do that.